Unity Material sets assigned Texture to null
My goal is to import a model into Unity and to assign an embedded texture in the model to a new material. I'm able to manually create the material and assign the texture from the user interface just fine. However, trying to do this programmatically allows me to create and save the material to the assets folder but it does not have the textures I've assigned.
This is a snippet where I've confirmed that the texture exists and that the field is being set and has the reference to the texture in it.
public UnityEngine.Texture Texture;
public override Material PopulateMaterial()
{
    var material = new Material(Shader.Find("Skybox/Panoramic"));
    foreach (var asset in AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/huh.glb"))
    {
        Debug.Log(asset);
    }
    Debug.Log(Texture);
    Debug.Log(material.mainTexture);
    material.SetColor("_Tint", Color.green);
    material.SetTexture("_MainTex", Texture);
    Debug.Log(material.mainTexture);
    return material;
}

The texture exists, the material's main texture is null, we set the texture, we read the material's main texture again and can see that it is set and clearly has the reference. The texture should not be null when we check the editor correct?

Here you can see that in this case, the first texture 49 is being used from the embedded textures in this model.

And despite the fact that we very clearly set the texture to the first texture called 49 which is embedded in this model file, it remains null when we check it in the editor.

I tried calling AssetDatabase.SaveAssets() and AssetDatabase.Refresh() but since this during an import, I get the error Calls to "AssetDatabase.SaveAssets" are restricted during asset importing and Calls to "AssetDatabase.Refresh" are restricted during asset importing. My current working theory is that there's something I need to do or call to "finalize" the import process to allow the reference to not be cleared out by Unity.
I also tried going the route of manually cloning the texture and trying to use that but I seem to be faced with the same issue of having to wait for it to be completely done importing somehow? Different variants of AssetDatabase.LoadAsset and AssetDatabase.ImportAsset didn't seem to do very much, didn't provide any useful information and does not have good documentation.
All I want to do is to set a texture on a material after it's finished importing which I feel in theory it should be already since I'm able to use it? Yet it doesn't seem like Unity has a feature that allows me to do this.
Additionally I'm using this library to import the glb file: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF/tree/main

But you never appear to set Texture to anything

Could you point out which line in the log belongs to which code line exactly? You have various Debug.Log there and it is a bit hard from only that to pin point what exactly is happening ;)

Is the Spherical (HDR)  - which I assume is the one you are talking about - actually mapped to the mainTexture property - so it has to be either called _MainTex or attributed [MainTexture] - in the shader? Are you sure you are actually looking on the correct material? The one you just created new ... what are you further doing with it?
